# Imitating Apache Camel DefaultErrorHandler

Tags: apache-camel

I was trying to handle exceptions using custom processor. My route builder looked something like this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(0)
    .process(exceptionProcessor)
    .handled(true)
    .to("file:C:\\Mahesh\\delete\\failedrequests");
```

My exception processor looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionProcessor implements Processor 
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = ExLoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception 
    {
        Exception ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
        Object messageHistroy = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY, Object.class);

        LOGGER.error("\n\nMessage History\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" 
                    + messageHistroy 
                    +"\n\nStacktrace\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
                    );
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, above I am trying to imitate [`DefaultErrorHandler`](http://camel.apache.org/defaulterrorhandler.html)'s behavior: it first prints message history and then stack trace.

However my `ExceptionProcessor` does not prints message history in the same way as in case of `DefaultErrorHandler`. `DefaultErrorHandler` prints it like this:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://C:%5CMahesh%5Cdelete%5Ccamelsource                                     ] [       121]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x35a764c7                                                          ] [       120]
[                  ] [to1               ] [file:C:\Mahesh\delete\badworkitems                                            ] [        98]
```

Whereas my `ExceptionProcessor` prints it like this:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=process2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=null, node=process1]]
```

**Q.** It seems that my processor is not able to get third column of processors and third row of to-endpoint. How do I get this.

Also, before printing message history, `DefaultErrorHandler` also prints this:

```
o.a.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-01HW865638-58603-1492677082431-0-7 on ExchangeId: ID-01HW865638-58603-1492677082431-0-8). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
at [Source: C:\Mahesh\delete\camelsource\file1.json; line: 4, column: 3]. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[sendTo(file://C:%5CMahesh%5Cdelete%5Cbadworkitems)]]
```

**Q.** As you can see, `DefaultFaultHandler` is also able to print message id, exchange id, source file name and send-to folder name. I was wondering from where it gets this information. For source file name, I tried all `Exchange.FILE_*` properties, but all printed `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the Camel source code how it prints that information, as it uses the message history which you also have access to. You can find the source code on github.

https://github.com/apache/camel/